# NemoJs vs NightWatchJS ? Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

i'm pretty much new to both the frameworks. seems like nightwatch has better documentation and extensive api compared to Nemo ?

What are major advantages in using one over another ?

Answer (score 1):

Nemo has no BDD tool inbuilt. You need to use something like Cucumber. Whereas Nightwatch comes along with its own BDD. There is even an option to pair it with Cucumber.

Comment: Nightwatch has great docs compared to Nemo.
Nightwatch has many features inbuilt compared to Nemo. Minor features like screenshot capture, skipTags, skipGroups, etc
Nightwatch supports both Saucelabs & Browserstack. Nemo supports Saucelabs but not sure about Browserstack.